# Highlight selected item in GridView

Tags: java, android

This code displays images in a GridView.  It allows the user to select an item at which point a custom checkbox is checked and the area around the image is highlighted a different color.  (The image shrinks to show a highlighted border).

I've been programming a while but I learned Java & Android in a bit of a vacuum so I would like to get some input from those with more experience in these areas.

I'm open to any comments or criticism but I'm mostly interested in things more in the category of these.  Does anything violated best practices for Java or Android?  Is there anything where I've missed checking for a `null` pointer or `Exception`s that absolutely must be handled?  Anything else that would cause this to break or for someone to look at it and think I'm an idiot.

I know the scope of some variables, classes etc. could be more narrow.  I've left those as 'Public' since this may be used in more generic cases than the small bit of code I've posted.  For similar reasons, I've left the adapter & list variables as member variables instead of moving them to locals inside `onCreate()`.

In MainActivity:

```
private GridAdapter mAdapter = null;
private List<GridItem> mList = null;

private final static int[] imageArray = {R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3, R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // omitted some typical onCreate() stuff
    mList = new ArrayList<>();

    // open to ideas for a better way to do this
    for (int  imageId : imageArray) {
        try {
            BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), imageId, null);
            GridItem item = new GridItem(drawable);
            mList.add(item);
        } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "resource " + imageId + " not found");
        }
    }

    mAdapter = new GridAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.grid_item, mList);
    GridView gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    gridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            boolean isSelected = mList.get(i).isSelected();
            mList.get(i).setSelected(!isSelected);

            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

The item:

```
public class GridItem {

    private BitmapDrawable bitmap = null;
    private boolean isSelected = false;
    public GridItem(BitmapDrawable bitmap) {
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
    }
    // omitted getters & setters
}
```

The adapter:

```
public GridAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<GridItem> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    final int PADDING = 16;

    RelativeLayout itemLayout;

    // use existing Views when we can
    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        itemLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
    } else {
        itemLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView;
    }

    GridItem gridItem = getItem(position);
    if(gridItem != null) {
        // get your bitmap or list item etc. here
        BitmapDrawable bitmap = gridItem.getBitmap();
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        imageView.setBackground(bitmap);

        FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.image_frame);            
        ImageView checkBox = (ImageView)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.custom_check_box);

        if (gridItem.isSelected()) {
            frame.setPadding(PADDING, PADDING, PADDING, PADDING);
            checkBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_check_box_selected);
        } else {
            frame.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            checkBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_check_box_unselected);
        }
    }
    return itemLayout;
}
```